# Why is this Doctrine entity not being persisted?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata

I am working with a Symfony 2.7 application that uses the Sonata admin bundle. When a VideoDerivative entity changes state, I want to create a DistributedVideo entity. I have a listener that calls out to this service method:

```
public function distribute(VideoDerivative $videoDerivative)
{
    $distributedVideo = new DistributedVideo;
    $distributedVideo->setVideo(
        $videoDerivative->getVideo()
    );
    $distributedVideo->setMetaData(' ');
    $distributedVideo->setVideosData(' ');
    $distributedVideo->setImagesData(' ');
    $distributedVideo->setIsVideoDerivative(true);

    $this->entityManager->persist($distributedVideo);

    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $this;
}
```

I have confirmed that the method is being run, but no DistributedVideo entity is being saved to the database, and no exception is thrown. I have tried both `$this->entityManager->flush()` and `$this->entityManager->flush($videoDerivative)`. What are some reasons why this might be failing? What are some things I could try to attempt a fix?

Comment: Show us the `DistributedVideo ` and `VideoDerivative ` entities please. You probably are missing `persist` in `cascade`.